# Where is this css ' float: left ' coming from -- Jekyll

Tags: css, sass, css-float, jekyll

I'm using the Jekyll CMS

The header has a basic structure

```
<div class="top">

</div>


<div class="header-wrapper">

  <div class="header-left"><img src="/assets/images/lawmen1.png" alt="Law and Lawson Attorney at Law Lawyers City State"></div>
  <div class="header-right">
    <ul>
      <li><i class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-2x"></i>250 W. Main Street Suite 2510<br>City, State 90210</li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-2x"></i>(555) 555-555</li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-fax fa-2x"></i>(555) 555-5555</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

And here is the css

```
@import '1-tools/-tools-index';


.top{
  width:100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #1A1A1A;
}


.header-wrapper{

  @include outer-container;
  padding-bottom: 2.5em;


  .header-left{
    @include span-columns(4);
    height: 200px;
    img{
      display:block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 2.8em;
      height:285px;
      width:325px;
    }
  }

  .header-right{
    margin-top:2.5em;
    height: 200px;

    @include span-columns(8);
    ul{
      li{
        font-family: Garamond;
        color: grey-color-dark;
        font-size: 1.1em;
      }
    }

    i{
      padding:0.2em;
      height: 50px;
      width:50px;
      color: #d3bc5f;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

So, you can see that I've not purposefully used `float: left` in the css.

However, you can see in the screenshot of inspect element that Jekyll has generated `float: left` in the main.scss

Is the syntax that I'm using in the css affecting this? Such as . .

```
<div class = "outside">
 <div class = "left"></div>
 <div class = "right"></div>
</div

.outside {
 .left {

 }
 .right {

 }
 }
```

Is it okay to nest the css like that?

Comment: It's probably provided by the includes you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This come from the **_sass/1-tools/neat/grid/_span-columns.scss** file.
By reading the doc we learn that we can remove the `float` and the display property to `table-cell` by doing a :

```
@include span-columns(8, 'table');
```